# Any way to strip off some annotations by maven?

Tags: maven, annotations, maven-plugin

I wonder if there a way to strip off some annotations when '**maven build**' ?

For convenience reason , I annotate some 3rd party's annotation into my POJO , such as `javax.persistence.*` , `org.hibernate.annotations.*` , `org.apache.lucene.analysis.*` ... blah...blah.

It works well when I bundle them together and deploy to a JavaEE/Spring server/container.

But when developing Android , I want to **make the most reuse of my code/POJOs**. I want to directly import foobar.core.User instead of creating another foobar.android.User without 3rd party annotations. That is , I don't want the jar dependent on other spring/hibernate artifacts.

So , is there any way to strip off some annotations when running 'maven build' ? I just need to strip off 'some' 3rd party annotations , and keep custom core annotations.

So that I can build `foobar-core.jar` and `foobar-core-stripped.jar` **respectively or simultaneously**.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do exactly the same thing. I found an ant task that can strip annotations from compiled classes.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/purgeannorefs/

The maven ant plugin can then be used to call the ant task as part of your maven build.

I know it's a bit of a workaround. But better than having to maintain 2 copies of the pojo objects.

Comment: Thanks , it's useful. But still not a maven solution... :)

Comment: seems to have a maven plugin now, but the project itself is not available in maven central.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a non-maven tool that does the job, you aren't going to find a maven plugin. Mmake stub copies of the annotation classes put them in a jar, and add them into the classpath for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-antrun-plugin to do a find and replace on all annotations... I did this at the following answer to comment out all @XmlAttribute annotations:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036841/342745

Kind of hacky, but it worked for me.