# Is there a way to strip annotations when using the cxf-codegen-plugin for generating sources?

Tags: maven, annotations, cxf

I'm using the [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) to generate some classes from a WSDL.  After the sources are generated, a bunch of beans get deleted (we don't need them, just the service interfaces), but there is an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation in the generated source that references some of these deleted classes.  We don't need the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation at all, is there a way to tell the cxf-codegen-plugin to exclude certain annotations when generating sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding a  tag to a `maven-antrun-plugin`, commenting out all the `@XmlSeeAlso` instances:

```
<target>
    <replace file="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/x/x/x/Service.java" token="@XmlSeeAlso" value="//@XmlSeeAlso" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of generated code is to let it be as it is. The question is why would you like to delete files which i assume is manual work which is in contradiction to the idea of generated code.

Comment: An ant task deletes the files for me.  The files need to be deleted because they are duplicate beans created from an axis2 implementation.  I can't do anything about the schemas I'm given.

Comment: Hm. What i don't understand that you described the classes are not used. But here you write they are duplicates. Does that mean you get error messages during the generation process? Furthermore it's sound a little bit strange to me that you say the service interfaces uses those classes but you don't ?.

Comment: The bean classes that are created by the cxf-codegen-plugin are not used because they have already been generated as axis2 beans (I am adding a CXF interface to an axis2 project).  The service interface specifically tries to reference (not use) the ObjectFactory classes that are generated by the cxf-codegen-plugin.  There are no errors when generating.